# Magazine container with html css

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to create a magazine web app with transitions swipe left and right with fade in right and left.
I have tried with jQuery.mobile but I can't adapt to the height the background image my idea is create one web app universal for all android and ios devices adaptive by height.

Anybody knows any suggestion or help?

Comment: Give us some more details. It seems like you might need specific help with the jquery implementation as opposed to other options.

Comment: Its difficult for me explain me in english i will try, well i want to create a universal web app that adapt to all devices android and ios. The problem is that i need use a image for the background and then put textbox others images on the background. I need that have swipe gesture with animation to the page1 to page2 and the page2 to the page1. And an index for choose the page that i want charge. i have tried with image slider example in jquery.mobile but without succeded

Answer (score 0):

you can check this and create lef-right effect : http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: i have tried the example fullpage but any positive results is css for adapt to the height is  height:100%; ? thanks